# What's the minimal length of each side of an equilateral triangle that can get a square of 15 mm inside it?

Tags: triangles

If I want to know What's the minimal length of each side of an equilateral triangle that can get a square of which each of its sides is 15 mm, inside it (=inside the square)?. How to calculate it?
(I'm not looking for the answer, but I'm looking for the way or approach to solving it, for future self-solutions).

Comment: Is the 15 mm  side or a diagonal?

Comment: 15mm is each side of the square.

Comment: bracket the square with two 90-60-30 triangles, with the sides opposite the 60 angle being opposite sides of the square. Then put an equilateral triangle which sides of 15 mm on top.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a pic. You'll want the square as big as possible, so it'll be tangent on a side and touching at two corners. Once you have the pic, think about what angles you know, and what the ratios between sides are in the known shapes (ex: squares have same sides, (30-60-90) triangles have $1-\sqrt 3-2$ sides).

Comment: Each angle is 60 degrees, from here I'm kind of lost... Maybe more hints?

Comment: @Arithmetic-Enthusiast There are more than enough hints in this answer to solve the problem. Any more, and Eric would be feeding you the answer.

Comment: It feels _intuitively_ right that orienting the triangle with one of its sides overlapping a side of the square is what gives the smallest triangle ... but still something that could deserve more of a proof than just pointing at a drawing and saying it's obvious.

Comment: Yeah, I think it’s non-trivial to prove that but it’s intuitively obvious (and the OP just wanted an answer probably for a hs geometry class, so I doubt he cares about a rigorous proof). You can pretty easily make maximality arguments that at least three corners need to touch the sides of the triangle. From there, I would guess it takes some annoying algebra to show that an edge touching is optimal.